# Writing a table and string to a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and have tried looking in matworks for a solution but have had no success.

My code produces a string and table that looks like this

Run number 3

Slope -0.00354, Intercept 0.02289

```
 x         y        Predictied_y
___    _________    ____________

  0            0     0.022894   
 30    -0.070808    -0.083405
  .            .            .
  .            .            .
  .            .            .
  .            .            .
```

My issue is that I can't seem to get the dlmwrite function to work at all. I've tried converting the table into an array with no success and I;m now stuck.

To make things worse the code has to write this table into the file three times without writing over the data in the file.

Sorry if I left out any details.

Comment: I don't understand what your code does now, and what you want it to do. Are you trying to read the table into matlab or produce the table in matlab?

Comment: `dlmwrite` is intended for matrices, use `writetable` instead.